# Use the variable after block successful completion

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks, instagram

I'm working on a simple instagram project now.
for several occasions I've encountered the same problem.
To work with instagram I use InstagramKit Engine. It has some preset (void)s to make life easier. However I'm always stuck at the same problem.

Let's say we've got this:

```
- (void)getSelfUserDetails
{
    [[InstagramEngine sharedEngine] getSelfUserDetailsWithSuccess:^(InstagramUser *userDetail) {

        NSLog(@"%@",userDetail);

    } failure:^(NSError *error) {
   }];
}
```

Here userDetail is used inside of the "Success". And it works nice. What I need is to somehow save it after the block is done.

I've tried several things from creating a property to store the userDetails up to making my own method to return the userDetails. The same trouble with saving ints, NSStrings etc..

I think I'm missing some easy way out.

Show it to me please.

Comment: It would help if you described what issue you are having when trying to use the `userDetail` value. Keep in mind that the "success" block is being called asynchronously so perhaps you are not taking that into account.

Comment: I thought about "success"'s asynchrony yesterday trying to get user's status (followed/follows). It's stored in a NSDictionary. And everytime I try to save the whole dictionary inside of a "success" and then NSLog it after the whole function thing, I get (null).
As i understood, program continues running and the NSLog line is executed milliseconds before the Dictionary is received.
I managed to walk it around by doing everything I need inside of a "success", but i feel bad because of the method being clearly unproductive. I feel there should be some easier solutions.

Comment: what the hack are voids? you are talking about blocks.

Comment: yeah, my fault. I concentrated on the (void), missing out the [...] things =\ Corrected the question. Thanks.

Comment: What is the trouble you are getting in saving?

Answer (score 0):

You need to capture an object in the block that you can send the response object.
This can be self.

```
-(void)processUserDetails:(InstagramUser *) userDetail
{
    //....
}

- (void)getSelfUserDetails
{
    [[InstagramEngine sharedEngine] getSelfUserDetailsWithSuccess:^(InstagramUser *userDetail) {
        [self processUserDetails: userDetail];
    } failure:^(NSError *error) {
   }];
}
```

Comment: I see the point. Have just tried it. s I understand, I won't get the result if I NSLog the variable i receive after the [self getSelfUserDetails]; int the main function. Everything I need to do I have to do in the "processUserDetails" void. Right?

Comment: I meant the function I am executing the [self getSelfUserDetails]; in.

Comment: and why again `void`? these are methods. Also the calling method (your main) will most likely finish before the block is executed.

Comment: About "void" - Wasn't sure about english word for it so just named it by the word in brackets.
the block is slower, but I think I'll be able to use it this way.
Thanks for the answer.

Comment: How will this produce a retain cycle if self does not hold a reference to Instagram Engine?

Comment: @BenjaminJimenez, Right, no retain cycle here. I usually avoid to work with singletons, so I would hold the engine in a property of self. This would create a retain cycle.

Comment: @Deimos, the block isn't slow – it just won't be called until there is something to work with. In ur case a network call response.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a property to hold the Instagram user that you find and assign it to it in the success block:

```
 @property (nonatomic) InstagramUser *myUser;


- (void)getSelfUserDetails
{
    [[InstagramEngine sharedEngine] getSelfUserDetailsWithSuccess:^(InstagramUser *userDetail) {

        NSLog(@"%@",userDetail);
        self.myUser = userDetail;
    } failure:^(NSError *error) {
   }];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a good use for an NSNotification (since the call above happens asynchronously).

You could call it like:

```
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
        postNotificationName:@"TestNotification" 
        object:self
        userInfo:@{ @"userDetail" : userDetail }
   ];
```

And then get that userInfo data back with whatever method is listening for that event.